# Как сделать чтобы информация с одной страницы передавалась на другие

Tags: html, html5, html-form

Мне нужно передать информацию с одной страницы на другие. Ниже представлен код, как сделать, чтобы информация котороя вводится в форму передаватась помимо главной страницы ещё и на другие?

Сам код предоставлен на фотографиях.введите сюда описание изображения
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `js` => `cookie`, `localStorage`

Comment: Не совсем понял как это реализовать(

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Исправьте вопрос, чтобы ваш код был в текстовом блоке. Для этого нажмите [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1396402/edit) под самим вопросом

Comment: @ВладиславБогачев не поленитесь, загуглите. Это азы. Там ничего сложного. При помощи cookie или localStorage можно сохранить какие то данные, затем в нужный момент вставить их в нужное место. Изучите азы